# Proof verification: the homology groups of the cube.

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I was so proud of this solution about finding the homology  groups of the cube $I\times I \times I$ but then a friend of mine make me feel uncomfortable about it. My "proof" is this:

> The homology groups of the square are $H_0(I\times I)=\mathbb{Z} $,  $H_1(I\times I)=0 $ and $H_2(I\times I)=\mathbb{Z} $. Since $I \times I  $ is a deformation retract of $ I \times I\times I$ we have $H_0(I\times I\times I)=\mathbb{Z} $,  $H_1(I\times I\times I)=0 $ and $H_2(I\times I\times I)=\mathbb{Z} $.

My friend said this:

> Your proof may be wrong since you are calculating the homology group of the shell of the cube and the square is a deformation retract of the cube with but not of the shell of the cube.

Who's wrong?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Second homology of the square is trivial.

Comment: Also all these things are contractible so...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you stopped. It's also true that $I \times I$ retracts onto $I$, and $I$ retracts onto $pt$. In other words, they are all trivial.

If you meant to do $\partial (I^3)$, then the homology is right, but your argument is wrong.